# Layer 2, layer 3, and blade switch problems

Tags: switch, vlan

I am in desperate need of your help.

I am an intern working on implementing a private cloud for a company.

The hardware is:

- layer 2 switch connected to the company network `192.1.1.0/24`
- layer 3 switch (huwaei s5700-si) connected to a
  firewall (`192.168.10.254` ip address of the management
  interface), firewall is connected to the `192.1.1.0/24`
- c7000 blade system containing 4 hp Proliant gen 9 servers
- Cisco Catalyst Blade Switch 3020 for HP.

So, I want to create these VLANs:

[image]

I configured the port `GigabitEthernet 0/0/1` (of the layer 3 switch) as follows:

```
port hybrid tagged vlans 1,50-52,55-63
ip-subnet vlan enable
```

this port is connected to `GigabitEthernet 1/0/25` of the blade switch, configured like this:

```
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlans all
```

`GigabitEthernet 1/0/24` of the blade switch is connected to the layer 2, and the management interface `fa0/0` has the address of `192.1.1.166`.

So, if I connect to the company network, I can ping to the blade switch, but from the layer 3 switch, I cant. Keep in mind that I can ping from the layer 3 to any address in the network, but not to 192.1.1.166.

My ultimate goal is to be able to give virtual machines hosted on esxi hypervisors running on the Proliant servers an address from the newly created VLANs, and be able to ping to them and from them.

I created all these VLANs on the layer 3 with their indicated subnets and gateways, and I am able to ping the gateways.

Comment: You are going to need to give us a diagram and the configurations of the devices involved.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you want to do is to do a trunked ports between your 3020's and the LAN.  ESXi vSwitch will be able to allow you to put VM's in particular VLAN's.

As for the firewall, it would trunk to the LAN also, being the gateway between the protected and non-protected subnets.  For non-firewalled VLAN's, the gateway could be the s5700.

So, each networking device (and host) has atleast (2) trunked links to a switch fabric (stack).  This is the typical design I see.

Comment: i forget to mention that i tried trunk between s5700 and the blade switch but the problem persists, this is my first time touching actual switches and network devices so please bare with me :)